# Explicit Linking DLL from C++ Project - (7zip, 7z.dll)

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli, 7zip

I am trying to use 7zip from within my application code. On 7zip's website, they say I can use 7z.dll. So, I tried to reference it from C#, but that didn't work. So, I decided to write a C++ library that references 7z.dll, and then I can reference that library from C#.

I was able to load the library (I think) in my C++ library, and I am able to reference that library from C# and successfully call a method.

However, I don't know how to figure out the method names inside the 7z.dll library so that I can call them.

Please help

Comment: Can you show an example of how you're presently calling a function in your test code?

Comment: And where did you read about linking against 7z.dll? On their website I see mostly references to the [SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html), which is somewhat different.

Comment: http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html

scroll to the bottom: How can I add support for 7z archives to my application?

Comment: @Cameron, I don't have an example call, because I haven't figured out how to know what methods/functions can be called. All I have done is write a line of code that loads the library (LoadLibrary("7z.dll")).

Comment: Aha, cool. It seems they provide an example for C++. Since it's done via COM, though, there's no need to manually write a C++/CLI wrapper; C# has excellent COM interop support. I'll see if I can whip up an example.

Comment: https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Hans Passant pointed out SevenZipSharp which makes my answer rather useless ;-) I'll leave it for purely educational purposes. No need to write your own COM interop wrappers if somebody else has already done it for you...

---

I had a look at their C++ example (under CPP/7zip/UI/Client7z). Everything is done using COM interfaces and various types of callbacks.

While C# has excellent COM interop support, it would require redeclaring the relevant COM interfaces in C#, or perhaps using late-bound `dynamic` magic instead. However, both of these options are rather non-trivial for a project the size of 7z, so on second thought it's likely best to stick with your C++/CLI wrapper approach.

Within that example, you can see exactly how `main` does it: It loads the DLL (using a wrapper class `NDLL::CLibrary` around the `LoadLibrary` call), then obtains a pointer to the COM `CreateObject` function (via the same wrapper that does a `GetProcAddress` internally).

Once you have the address of the `CreateObject` function, you can call it with the appropriate application and interface GUIDs to obtain instances of objects that implement them, after which you can use those objects to do the actual work. The interfaces themselves are declared in header files such as `IArchive.h`.